# How to get a loading spinner image with the ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please suggest me the logic to use the getSpinner() with my ajax call to show and hide the spinner image on beforeSend and complete ajax call. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

I have an Ajax call as :

```
$j.ajax({ 
type : "POST", 
url : //service call, 
data : JSON.stringify(request_data), 
contentType : "application/json", 
dataType : "json", 
async : false, //Forcing this sync 
success : function (result) { 
  //logic to generate pdf
}
```

I have the getSpinner() function as :

```
function getSpinner() {
    var loadingimage = $j('<div id="spinner" class="spinnerdiv"><img id="img-spinner" class="ajax-spinner" src="rotation.gif"></div>');
    return loadingimage;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already have your html elements on the page first. Then you can define 2 separate functions to show and hide the spinner

Your js edited a bit

```
function getSpinner() {
  var loadingimage = '<div id="spinner" class="spinnerdiv">
  <img id="img-spinner" class="ajax-spinner" src="rotation.gif" />
  </div>'
  return loadingimage;
 }

$j.ajax({ 
type : "POST", 
url : //service call, 
data : JSON.stringify(request_data), 
contentType : "application/json", 
dataType : "json", 
async : false, //Forcing this sync
beforeSend: function(){
  var spinnerHtml = getSpinner();
   //check that it doesn't exist
  if($('#spinner').length < 1){
   //add spinner
   $("WhereYouWantItToGo").html(spinnerHtml);
  }
}

success : function (result) { 
  //logic to generate pdf
},
error : function(){

},
complete : function(){
    //check that it does exist and remove
    if($('#spinner').length > 0){
      $('#spinner').remove();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I dont have the div on my html so I have to use function getSpinner(). Can u suggest a way with function getSpinner().

Answer (score 0):

try this i tried like this. and it's really working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#loading')
            .hide()
            .ajaxStart(function() {
                $(this).show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
    });
</script>

<div id="loading">
        Loading....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gaurav.. can you please try using getSpinner() in ajax. Thanks!

Comment: can u give me any url where i can try